# Burning sound from the PSU

Tags: power-supply, voltage, voltage-regulator, buck, step-down

I am trying to make  a bench power supply from an old 350W PC PSU
that provides 4 lines

1. 3.3V 8A
2. 5V 9A
3. 12V 11A
4. -12V 1.5A

Here is the connections diagram:
[image: connections diagram]

I used this step down module to be able the adjust the voltage and current limit on the 12V and -12V lines: "[DC-DC Converter Step Down Module 12A](https://makerselectronics.com/product/dc-dc-converter-step-down-module-12a#:%7E:text=Add%20your%20review-,DC%2DDC%20Converter%20Step%20Down%20Module%2012A,-160.00%C2%A0EGP%22)"

I used this display to monitor voltage and current: "[DC 0-100V 10A Digital Voltmeter and Ammeter Dual Display](https://makerselectronics.com/product/dc-0-100v-10a-digital-voltmeter-and-ammeter-dual-display)"

The problem is that when I try to increase the voltage using the potentiometers of the step down module, I hear a burning sound.  I don't know what it is, but I feel like if I don't decrease it fast it will burn something. The burning sound increases very much with the voltage increase

Here is a video for the problem [Burning sound](https://www.veed.io/view/e3147795-e372-44ba-befb-7abdf5da817b?panel=share)

Is the problem from the step down module, or is it from the PSU?

Comment: What is a "burning sound"? Different things make different sounds when they burn.

Comment: Where did the sound come from?

Comment: @brhans yes you are right, this is the video "https://www.veed.io/view/e3147795-e372-44ba-befb-7abdf5da817b?panel=share"

Comment: Please stop using the power supply before it creates an accident. Disconnect it from the power outlet. Check the PCB with a multimeter. I guess, a short circuit is happening.

Comment: @Andyaka i really don't know that is why i am asking but i took a video for it "https://www.veed.io/view/e3147795-e372-44ba-befb-7abdf5da817b?panel=share"

Comment: @liaifat85 But why do I only hear this sound when I increase the voltage?

Comment: Why are you using +12 and -12 outputs for the step down regulator? That makes no sense. Also, if you have not noticed, most questions here about using old PC power supplies for custom purposes like lab power supplies are about why they don't work when used for custom purposes.

Comment: @justme i am using +12V and -12V to get 24V and be able the adjust it using step down regulator, but what is the problem with that i think  theoretically it should work

Comment: @MohamedEssam Of course everything should work in theory and in ideal world. However the supply can output say 10A or more of +12V and maybe max 1A of -12V, so you will damage it. It is not intended to put load between +12V and -12V, at least not if it is more than say 100mA for analog op-amps or similar.

Comment: Is it the PSU from https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/685606/can-i-use-12-v-and-12-v-together with max 1.5 A to  -12 V? That information probably should be edited into the question.

Comment: @sillis Yes it is, thank you i will add them

Comment: For what it's worth, I'd describe that sound as a ratchet-like sputtering or rattling sound. I don't know what the phrase "burning sound" is supposed to mean.

Comment: Did you check for *minimum* loads on the PC PSU's outputs - and provide them?

Comment: @greybeard I didn't put load at all. i am just trying to increase the voltage without connecting anything

Comment: @liaifat85 Thank you, you were right it was a short circuit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was because of i had installed the step down module on the body of the PSU and a pin of the soldured pins of the step down module was making a short circuit with the PSU body, so i just put an insulator between them :)